# linux overwrite running binary

Tags: c, linux

How would i do this in linux using C ?
I need to write update function that downloads update using wget, then replaces old file with an update, and then starts update file.
One idea was using bash script but that didn't work out.
Any suggestions?

EDIT:here is code similiar to what i tried

```
char *p_name = "example"; /* name of the running executable */

void update(char *update_url)
{
        if(!fork())
                /* download file to temporary location */
                execlp("wget", "wget" "-q", update_url, "-O", "tmp", NULL);
        wait(NULL);
        FILE *fp = fopen("tmp.sh", "w");
        /* write bash script */
        fprintf(fp, "sleep 5\nmv tmp %s\nchmod +x %s\nrm tmp.sh",
                p_name, p_name);
        fclose(fp);
        execlp("bash", "bash", "tmp.sh", NULL);
}
```

Comment: What you want to do should in principle work as you described. Please provide more information on what exactly went wrong (ideally the actual code and the errors you got).

Comment: If it is running-loaded in the memory, the real problem is how you will switch from the running process, to the new process which contains the update code.

Comment: What did you try? How did you fail? Linux allows replacing open files and running binaries. I'd guess you had permssion issues (binary owned by root, update running as normal user or such)

Answer (score 8):

Overwriting a running program doesn't actually overwrite the file, it basically creates a new file, while marking the old file to be removed when the program exits.

After your script have downloaded the new program, you have to `kill` the running program, and then restart it. It will start with the new program.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to kill the program, you can just `exec` it.

Comment: This is actually wrong. There is a difference between overwriting a file, and replacing the file. It is safe to replace a library by using `rename` or the `mv` shell command. It is **not safe** to open the file for write and replace the contents.